# Can someone make me understand the defination of connectionMade here in this piece of twisted proxy code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, twisted

```
def connectionMade(self):

    self.factory.request.channel.connectedRemote = self
    self.factory.request.setResponseCode(200, "CONNECT OK")
    self.factory.request.setHeader('X-Connected-IP',
                                   self.transport.realAddress[0])
    self.factory.request.setHeader('Content-Length', '0')
    self.factory.request.finish()
```

What does the above piece of code actually do ?
Also why the setHeader has been used two times  to set the header?

Comment: Did you have the chance to read the answer?

Answer (score 2):

this line stores the factory in the connected channel

```
self.factory.request.channel.connectedRemote = self
```

this sets the answer to 200: it is the HTTP code to signal the fact the asnwer is correct

```
self.factory.request.setResponseCode(200, "CONNECT OK")
```

these two lines add two headers to the answer and for this reason it is called twice; one for each of the headers that are needed to the HTTP Client to understand the answer

```
self.factory.request.setHeader('X-Connected-IP',
                               self.transport.realAddress[0])
self.factory.request.setHeader('Content-Length', '0')
```

this line of code signal to the factory the fact that the request is correctly finished and maybe flush the related stream

```
self.factory.request.finish()
```

Comment: great explaination ,,,,,,,,,,,,,